# cURL Post Data in PHP not sending?

Tags: php, curl

I'm Having trouble with using "Post" with cURL in PHP. I am sending a post request with the following code, but it acts like I never sent anything to it at all.

```
/* STEP 1. let’s create a cookie file */

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

/* STEP 2. visit the homepage to set the cookie properly */

$ch = curl_init ("http://im.storm8.com/apoints.php?fpts=12&version=a1.54&udid=istormtesting&pf=e5170941df8053ae3ab4e84e7dff756b&model=Droid&sv=2.2");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

/* STEP 3. invite */

//set POST variables
$mob = "YRKE5X";
$url = 'http://im.storm8.com/group.php';
$fields = array(
                    'mobcode' => urlencode($mob)
            );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


//execute post
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); } else { echo 'Operation completed without any errors'; } 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
//close connection
curl_close($ch); ?>
```

The issue is up live here: http://gdog.x10.mx/stats/addme.php

Comment: To symplify your code use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 1):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Comment: This is not the problem, because he already has `count($fields)` as parameter, and every number that is not `0` will be true.

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't fix it. Thanks for the response though.